# Qt5 using daylight savings time for embedded device from NTP server time

Tags: android, qt, timezone, dst

I'm trying to account for daylight savings in an app I'm working on but it's not working. The app itself runs on ARM based board with no system battery to keep time so I am reading the time from an NTP server.

Now in a test app running on the device using this in Qt5:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTimeZone>

#include <QDebug>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <memory.h>

time_t getNTPTime()
{
    char host[] = "192.168.1.16";

    qDebug() << "NTP request from host" << host;

    int     socket_descriptor = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 );
    if ( socket_descriptor < 0 ) return 0;

    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    memset( &client_addr, 0, sizeof(client_addr) );
    client_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( INADDR_ANY );
    client_addr.sin_port = htons( 0 );

    if ( bind( socket_descriptor, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, sizeof(client_addr)) < 0 )
        return 0;

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    memset( &server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr) );
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( host );
    server_addr.sin_port = htons( 123 );

    char buf[1024];
    memset( buf, 0, 1024 );

    char request[48];
    memset( request, 0, 48 );
    request[0] = 0x1b;

    if ( sendto( socket_descriptor, request, 48, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr) ) < 0 )
        return 0;

    struct sockaddr_in recv_addr;
    socklen_t recv_addr_len = sizeof( recv_addr );
    int rcvd = recvfrom( socket_descriptor, buf, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&recv_addr,&recv_addr_len );

    qDebug() << rcvd << "bytes received from NTP server <-- NTP REQUEST";

    unsigned long ntpTime = ( buf[40] << 24 ) + ( buf[41] << 16 ) +
                            ( buf[42] << 8  ) +   buf[43];

    ntpTime -= 2208988800UL;    // take off 70 years

    qDebug() << "ntpTime =" << ntpTime;

    return ntpTime;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    time_t ntptime = getNTPTime();
    QDateTime time;

    qDebug() << "System time zone" << QTimeZone::availableTimeZoneIds();

    QTimeZone qZone( "UTC+00:00" );
    time.setTimeSpec( Qt::TimeZone );
    time.setTimeZone( qZone );
    time.setTime_t( ntptime );

    //time.addSecs( 3600 );

    qDebug() << time.toString();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Gives me the in the debug output a list of timezones available for the arm device:

```
D/Qt      ( 4701): ..\TimeZoneTest\main.cpp:15 (time_t getNTPTime()): NTP request from host 192.168.1.16
D/Qt      ( 4701): ..\TimeZoneTest\main.cpp:49 (time_t getNTPTime()): 48 bytes received from NTP server <-- NTP REQUEST
D/Qt      ( 4701): ..\TimeZoneTest\main.cpp:56 (time_t getNTPTime()): ntpTime = 1414581684
D/Qt      ( 4701): ..\TimeZoneTest\main.cpp:68 (int main(int, char**)): System time zone ("UTC", "UTC+00:00", "UTC+01:00", "UTC+02:00", "UTC+03:00", "UTC+03:30", "UTC+04:00", "UTC+04:30", "UTC+05:00", "UTC+05:30", "UTC+05:45", "UTC+06:00", "UTC+06:30", "UTC+07:00", "UTC+08:00", "UTC+09:00", "UTC+09:30", "UTC+10:00", "UTC+11:00", "UTC+12:00", "UTC+13:00", "UTC+14:00", "UTC-00:00", "UTC-01:00", "UTC-02:00", "UTC-03:00", "UTC-03:30", "UTC-04:00", "UTC-04:30", "UTC-05:00", "UTC-06:00", "UTC-07:00", "UTC-08:00", "UTC-09:00", "UTC-10:00", "UTC-11:00", "UTC-12:00", "UTC-13:00", "UTC-14:00")
D/Qt      ( 4701): ..\TimeZoneTest\main.cpp:77 (int main(int, char**)): "Wed Oct 29 11:21:24 2014 GMT"
```

So at the moment I'm stuck on how to implement daylight savings.

I came to the conclusion after this Sunday and the main app I am working on didn't make any changes to the time. As with the above output, there's no timezone settings available for the device for GMT. It appears that at the moment I may have to check whether the app is within the DST date range and adjust manually.

Does anybody know how to work with daylight savings in Qt5 for embedded devices? Or does this mean a manual way around it?

Comment: I don't know about qt, but any solution you come up with should be using time zones from [the tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

Comment: I've had a good read into the tz database and many other pages regarding timezones and not come up with a solution based on a timezone. But, I have found a way around it as the Android app runs alongside a PC based database which can output it's time at regular intervals, this assuming the PC's clock adjusts correctly. And voila, that's that problem solved. It is a workaround solution, but in this instance it fixes it.